# How to force node.status=0

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I need to force the status value of a node=0 when the user has a certain role.

I've made

```
 function mymodule_node_save($node){
    if($node->type=="mytype") {
        global $user;
        if(in_array("simple",$user->roles)) {
            $node->status=0;
        }

    }
}
```

But the status is always saved as 1. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You might also want to use constants NODE_PUBLISHED and NODE_NOT_PUBLISHED instead of 1 and 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not hook_node_save() in Drupal 7, but there is a hook_node_presave() that is fire when saving or updating content. So your code should look like:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node){
    if($node->type=="mytype") {
        global $user;
        if(in_array("simple",$user->roles)) {
            $node->status=0;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[@redhatlab](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/8010/redhatlab) is correct about Drupal 7 not invoking `hook_node_save()`. If you need to be sure the status is effectively set to 0, without other modules to alter it, I would use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  mymodule_update_status($node);
}

function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  mymodule_update_status($node);
}

function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'node_insert' || $hook == 'node_update') {
    $group = $implementations['mymodule'];
    unset($implementations['mymodule']);
    $implementations['mymodule'] = $group;
  }
}

function mymodule_update_status($node){
  if ($node->type == 'mytype' && in_array('simple', $GLOBALS['user']->roles)) {
    $node->status = 0;
  }
}
```

The code checks the roles assigned to the currently logged-in user. If you want to check the roles assigned to the node author, you should use `$node->uid` to load the user object of the node author. It is then generally preferable to check the user has a specific permission, rather then checking which roles are assigned to the user.

`node_save()` first invokes `hook_node_presave()`, and then `hook_node_insert()`, or `hook_node_update()`. The code I wrote would allow your module to be the last one changing the node status.

#### References

- [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7)
- [hook_module_implements_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7)