# db-update is not working

Tags: database

Node status does not change.
If I set status = 1 it works fine.

```
function yt_common_changes_mark_spam($args) {
  $num_updated = db_update('node') // Table name no longer needs {}
    ->fields(array('status' => 0))
    ->condition('nid', $args, '=')
    ->execute();
  // $result = db_query("UPDATE {node} SET status = %d", $args) ;
  if($num_updated) {
     drupal_set_message('Content Mark as Spam successfully'.$args);
     drupal_goto('node/');      
  } else{     
      drupal_set_message('Content did not Mark as Spam successfully'.$args);
      drupal_goto('node/'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope now it looks like you wanted to? There is a "code" button on the editor's toolbar. Paste your code, select it, and click that button - easiest and safest way.

Comment: Seems [there was similar issues](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/48308/16495), but with less direct approach. Don't know why this does not work. Have you checked database? If change appears in database, but node is still published, maybe you have problem with *node_revision* table?